# How to mock dom element from karma testing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

There is an input type file element. During angular file upload multiple times, the value is not being cleared. Hence manually clearing it using plain javascript dom manipulation.

Below is the code:

```
function removeFromQueue(item) {
        vm.uploads.uploader.removeFromQueue(item);
        // Clearing input file field for re-uploading
        if(!vm.uploadFile) {
            document.getElementById('upload-file-' + vm.type).value = null;
        }
    }
```

In this case, not able to mock the `document.getElementById`, hence controlling it using `vm.uploadFile` undefined variable from unit test case which is wrong. How to mock the dom element here?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You should be able to [**`spyOn`**](https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction#section-Spies) the `document.getElementById` and return the useful properties (i.e. `value` here). Like this,

```
spyOn(document, "getElementById").and.callFake(function() {
    return {
        value: 'test'
    }
});
```

And then if you want, you can expect it to have been called,

```
expect(document.getElementById).toHaveBeenCalledWith('...')
```

Comment: in this example, how does the test know which id is being called? for example, the id: 'upload-file-upload-file-' + vm.type` isn't being passed anywhere in your example.
edit: removed template literal to match OPs example

Comment: after upgrading to "@types/jasmine": "^3.4.0" the same code throws error